# std map composite key

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a problem with the *operator<()* method which is required for a std::map. I'm using a struct as composite key that looks as follows:

```
struct MyKey {
  std::string string1;
  std::string string2;
  std::string string3;
  unsigned int uint1;

  friend bool operator<(const MyKey& mk1, const MyKey& mk2)
  {
    return mk1.string1 < mk2.string1 && mk1.string2 < mk2.string2 &&
           mk1.string3 < mk2.string3 && mk1.uint1 < mk2.uint1;
  }
}
```

As introduced I want to use a composite key with 4 values, but I don't know how to achieve this for the *operator<* method. I observed that only 1 value is stored at a time!

Can anybody tell me how the right condition looks like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Standard library's *associative containers* such as `std::map`, `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::multimap`, `std::bitset` require that the ordering of elements must follow [`Strict Weak Ordering`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), which means your implementation of `operator<` must follow [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). So one implementation could be this:

```
friend bool operator<(const MyKey& mk1, const MyKey& mk2)
{
  if (mk1.string1 != mk2.string1 )
       return mk1.string1 < mk2.string1;

  else if ( mk1.string2 != mk2.string2)
       return mk1.string2 < mk2.string2;

  else if (mk1.string3 != mk2.string3)
       return  mk1.string3 < mk2.string3;

  else
       return mk1.uint1 < mk2.uint1;
}
```

Or you can implement it as:

```
friend bool operator<(const MyKey& mk1, const MyKey& mk2)
{
  auto const & t1 = std::tie(mk1.string1, mk1.string2, mk1.string3, mk1.uint1);
  auto const & t2 = std::tie(mk2.string1, mk2.string2, mk2.string3, mk2.uint1);
  return t1 < t2;
}
```

In this solution, [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) function creates two tuples `t1` and `t1` of the references of the arguments passed to it, and then compare `t1` and `t2`  using overloaded `operator<` for `std::tuple` instead. The [operator<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) for tuple compares the elements lexicographically — strict-weak ordering is achieved..

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem in that the operator< doesn't necessarily implement strict weak ordering. There are too many combinations where `A<B` is false and `B<A` is also false, where `A` and `B` are `MyKey` objects. This is interpreted as `A` being equal to `B`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is that it's not stable, consider...

```
return mk1.string1 < mk2.string1 && mk1.string2 < mk2.string2 &&
       mk1.string3 < mk2.string3 && mk1.uint1 < mk2.uint1;
```

...evaluating `{ "a", "a", "a", 1 } < { "a", "b", "a", 1 }` = `a<a && ...` = `false && ...` = `false`

...but `{ "a", "b", "a", 1 } < { "a", "a", "a", 1 }` = `a<a && ...` = `false && ...` = `false`

So, neither is reported as less than the other, despite them not being equal keys in the `map`.

A working solution: it's concise and efficient to do each necessary string comparisons only once...

```
friend bool operator<(const MyKey& mk1, const MyKey& mk2)
{
    int x;
    return (x = mk1.string1.compare(mk2.string1)) ? x < 0 :
           (x = mk1.string2.compare(mk2.string2)) ? x < 0 :
           (x = mk1.string3.compare(mk2.string3)) ? x < 0 :
           mk1.uint1 < mk2.uint1;
}
```