# Which operator needs to be overridden in order to use std::set in the C++ code?

Tags: c++, class, set, overriding

This is an interview question.

> > Referring to the sample code, which one of the operators needs to be overridden in order to use  `std::set<Value>`

```
 #include<iostream>

 class Value
 {
      std::string   s_val;
      int           i_val;
  public:
      Value(std::string s, int i): s_val(s) , i_val(i){}
 };

 // EOF

 /*
 a       operator !=
 b       operator >
 c       operator <=
 d       operator >=
 e       operator <
 */
```

Actually, I do not understand why an operator needs to be overridden here. "set" does not allow duplicated elements, maybe operator != needs to be overridden ?

Comment: Overriding `operator!=` (or `operator==`) it would be difficult to maintain the complexity guarantees, don't you think? Still I find this question sort of sad...

Comment: -1 as you didn't appear to have tried to find out about what a std::set is and does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::set with user defined type, how to ensure no duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114856/stdset-with-user-defined-type-how-to-ensure-no-duplicates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't ***have*** to override any operator, the `std::set` class template allows you to provide a comparison function as a template parameter. But if you were to provide an operator, the one needed is `bool operator<()`. This operator has to implement [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). See this [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) documentation.

The reason strict weak ordering is used is because set is an ordered container, typically implemented as a self-balancing binary tree. So it is not enough to know whether two elements are the same or not. The set must be able to order them. And the less than operator or the comparator functor are also used to test for element equality.

Comment: I'm confused by your "you don't have to override any operator". *If* `std::set<Value>` is to be used, then `std::less<Value>` will be used by default. Doesn't this require `operator<`?

Comment: @Walter you can pass your own comparator as second template parameter to set, which then replaces the default, `std::less<Value>`. This is very handy because ofter you want to make sets containing objects of types that have no `operator <` and over which you have no control.

Comment: +1 okay, I misread your answer. Of course, **if** you provide the 2nd template argument, then you don't need to provide the `operator<`. And yes that can be very handy, in particular as you may not want to provide that operator as it may confuse other code, or (as you said) if there is already an `operator<` with another meaning than your intended ordering.

Comment: I would +1 this but the answer seems incomplete it contains no answer to the question, just a hint that the answer does exist somewhere! Syntax examples really help, especially with something that is described as just a second parameter.

Comment: @CoryTrese OP is asking which operators need to be overloaded, and I am answering that question. The references should be enough for anyone to figure out the rest.

Comment: The references were enough to get me started looking on Stack Overflow and eventually I found the answer to the sample code above (class Value into std::set) on another question, which i up-voted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `operator<` for your type. The implementation must follow **strick weak ordering** to be able to use with associative containers from Standard library such as `std::set` and `std::map`.

Read about:

- [Strict Weak Ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)

An example here:

- [std map composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276358/std-map-composite-key)

Answer (score 2):

A set keeps out the duplicates without needing `operator=` or `operator!=` by using the notion of equivalence. Two items are equivalent if neither is less than the other:

```
if (!(a < b || b < a))
    // equivalent!
```

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the enforcement of no duplicate elements and generally checking if element is in its usually some sort of a tree and only needs operator <. (The only usage of less is enforced by the standard, the rest is just the avarage implementation)